# No encuentro la solución o el error

Tags: javascript, array

La función llamada `fakeBinary` recibe como argumento un string con números y debe devolver un string en donde se remplaza los números menores de 5 con '0' y los números iguales o mayores a 5 con '1', por ejemplo:

```
fakeBinary2('5627') devuelve "1101"
fakeBinary("729") devuelve "101"
```

---

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
function fakeBinary2(string) {
  var arr = string.split('');
  var arr2 = [];
  for (var i = 0; i = arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < 5) {
      arr[i] = 0;
      arr2.push(arr[i]);
    }
    if (arr[i] >= 5) {
      arr[i] = 1;
      arr2.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return arr2;
  }
}
```

Comment: mueve `return arr2;` una línea abajo, y cambia `i = arr.length;` por `i < arr.length;`

Comment: Tu error está en que en donde deberia ir la condición del `for` estás haciendo una asignación a la variable `i` como ves: `(var i = 0; i = arr.length; i++)`. Lo cual por naturalidad de javascript te dará `false` y no se cumplira nunca el ciclo. Debería ser algo como `i < arr.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con este `for` estás haciendo un loop infinito:

```
for (var i = 0; i = arr.length; i++) { ... }
```

Tendría que ser:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { ... }
```

También, el `return arr2;` está mal ubicado, ya que al estar dentro del `for`, devolverás el resultado de la última iteración. Debería estar una línea más debajo, fuera del `for`.

---

Código:

```js
function fakeBinary(string) {
  var arr = string.split('');
  var arr2 = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < 5) {
      arr[i] = 0;
      arr2.push(arr[i]);
    }
    if (arr[i] >= 5) {
      arr[i] = 1;
      arr2.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return arr2;
}

console.log(fakeBinary("5627"));
console.log(fakeBinary("729"));
```

Comment: Perfecto! solucionado, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2):

Hay varios problemas en tu código:

1. Estás igualando `i = arr.length;` en el bucle, creando un bucle infinito. La forma de leer de este modo es `i < arr.length;`, [revisa la documentación al respecto y los ejemplos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).
2. Estás haciendo `return` en la primera iteracción del código.

Así funciona del modo esperado:

```js
console.log(fakeBinary('5627')) //devuelve "1101"
console.log(fakeBinary("729")) //devuelve "101"

function fakeBinary(string) {
  var arr = string.split('');
  var arr2 = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < 5) {
      arr2.push(0);
    } else {
      arr2.push(1);
    }
  }
  return arr2;
}
```

Aparte de eso, parecería que no se requiere un array como respuesta. En la pregunta viene dicho que la función: *debe devolver un string en donde se remplaza los números menores de 5 con '0' y los números iguales o mayores a 5 con '1'*. Si tal es el caso, puedes ir construyendo una cadena, y además simplificar con un ternario, si te está permitido (ignoro si es un ejercicio). Si es un ejercicio y debes usar `if`, simplemente lo cambias.

```js
console.log(fakeBinary('5627')) //devuelve "1101"
console.log(fakeBinary("729")) //devuelve "101"

function fakeBinary(string) {
  var arr = string.split('');
  var str = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    str += (arr[i] < 5) ? '0' : '1';
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: Lo que dice el amigo aca es muy cierto, si o si en la primera iteración del `for` se cerrará la función debido al `return`. Te recomiendo encarecidamente [indentar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estilo_de_sangrado) bien tu codigo.